# HKHealthStore is not adding correct Diet Energy value passed

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am trying to add user's calorie consumption to Apple health kit app. But the value is getting divided by thousand when it gets added to health app. Here is my code for adding to health kit.

```js
NSDictionary *calorieData = @{@"Unit": [HKUnit kilocalorieUnit], @"Identifier":HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed};

HKQuantity *quantity = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit] doubleValue:123];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
HKQuantityType *quantityType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed];
HKQuantitySample *sample = [HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:quantityType quantity:quantity startDate:now endDate:now metadata:metaData];

[[self healthStore] saveObject:sample withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    if (success)
        NSLog(@"Added");

}];
```

I am adding 123 kilo calories to health kit. After adding it is displaying as 123 Cal in health app. 
When I retrieve from HealthKit it is coming as 123 kcal.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calories with a capital "C" are equivalent to kilocalories. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie):

> The small calorie or gram calorie (symbol: cal) is the approximate
> amount of energy needed to raise the temperature of one gram of water
> by one degree Celsius at a pressure of one atmosphere.
>
> The large calorie or kilogram calorie (symbol: Cal), also known as the food
> calorie and similar names, is defined in terms of the kilogram
> rather than the gram. It is equal to 1000 small calories, 1
> kilocalorie (symbol: kcal).